# LIKE statement error in SQlite android query

Tags: android, sqlite

i had a problem about LIKE statement in sqlite android . i used one hours to figure out but i cannot get the error part . Anyone know where is my mistake ?

```
    public Cursor getSearch(String id) {

        String[] args = { id };


        return (database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.product_id
                + " as _id," 
                + SQLiteHelper.productName + " ," +SQLiteHelper.productDesp
                + "," + SQLiteHelper.productQtty + ","
                +SQLiteHelper.product_CategoryF+" FROM " 
                + SQLiteHelper.productTable+"  WHERE "
                + SQLiteHelper.productName +" LIKE 'id%'",null));
}
```

Error message

```
 bind or column index out of range: handle 0x5e3ec0
```

anyone know where is my mistake ?

Solution

```
return (database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.product_id
                + " as _id," 
                + SQLiteHelper.productName + " ," +SQLiteHelper.productDesp
                + "," + SQLiteHelper.productQtty + ","
                +SQLiteHelper.product_CategoryF+" FROM " 
                + SQLiteHelper.productTable+"  WHERE "
                + SQLiteHelper.productName +" LIKE '"+id+"%'",null));
```

Comment: check the syntax from  -----  ,"+SQLiteHelper.product_CategoryF+" FROM ". remove this  ,". And in like it should be like this "LIKE '"+id+"%'",null. Try this

Comment: okok , thx for help ...i know my mistake ald ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to form your SQL like that. `rawQuery` makes it very easy to bind arguments.

```
rawQuery("SELECT ? as _id, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM ? WHERE ? LIKE 'id%'", new String[] {SQLiteHelper.product_id, SQLiteHelper.productName, SQLiteHelper.productDesp, SQLiteHelper.productQtty, SQLiteHelper.product_CategoryF, SQLiteHelper.productTable, SQLiteHelper.productName});
```

As far as your code is concerned, notice `,"+` on your CategoryF line should be `+",`

```
    return (database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.product_id
            + " as _id," 
            + SQLiteHelper.productName + " ," +SQLiteHelper.productDesp
            + "," + SQLiteHelper.productQtty + ","
            ,"+SQLiteHelper.product_CategoryF+" FROM " 
            + SQLiteHelper.productTable+"  WHERE "
            + SQLiteHelper.productName +" LIKE 'id%'",null));
```